How to export certificate using wincrypt PFXExportCertStoreEx
I have created a self signed certificate with a root CA using openssl and loaded both the CA and user certificate into the windows cert store.
I can find it and get it's properties and extended properties.
It's enhanced key usage is:
Document Encryption
Domain Name System (DNS) Server Trust
SpcEncryptedDigestRetryCount
SpcRelaxedPEMarkerCheck
Document Signing
Secure Email
Client Authentication
I want to export the key. Is there a way to specify a single certificate to export? The only means I find in wincrypt API to obtain a certificate in PFX format is to export all the certificates in the store using FXExportCertStoreEx.
Trying to FXExportCertStoreEx I am running into an error.
The code below fails with ERROR: -858993460 Key not valid for use in specified state.
The first call to  PFXExportCertStoreEx returns a buffer size of 0 and the second call causes
ERROR: -858993460 Key not valid for use in specified state.
Why?
HCERTSTORE hCertStore;


if(! (hCertStore = CertOpenSystemStore(
            NULL,
            L"MY")))
{
    MyHandleError((wchar_t*)L"The MY store could not be opened.");
}

//Export CertStore to PFX

CRYPT_DATA_BLOB Blob;
ZeroMemory(&Blob, sizeof(CRYPT_DATA_BLOB));
if (!(PFXExportCertStoreEx(hCertStore,
        &Blob,
        L"342455",
        NULL,
        EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEYS |
        REPORT_NOT_ABLE_TO_EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEY |
        PKCS12_INCLUDE_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES |
        REPORT_NO_PRIVATE_KEY)==0))
{
    DWORD e = GetLastError();
    std::wstring ermsg = getErrorMsg();
    OutputDebugString(ermsg.c_str());

    std::wostringstream os;
    os << "Error getting buffer size when exporting certificates from store \n";
    os << "Error code" << GetLastError() << "\n";
    OutputDebugString(os.str().c_str());
    printf("Error sizing blob: 0x%x \n", GetLastError());
    goto fail;
}




if (Blob.pbData) HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, Blob.pbData);



Blob.pbData = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, Blob.cbData);
if (!Blob.pbData)
{
    printf("Error allocating data blob: %d\n", GetLastError());
    goto fail;
}

if (!PFXExportCertStoreEx(hCertStore,
        &Blob,
        L"342455",
        NULL,
        EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEYS |
        REPORT_NOT_ABLE_TO_EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEY |
        PKCS12_INCLUDE_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES |
        REPORT_NO_PRIVATE_KEY))
{
    DWORD e = GetLastError();
    std::wstring ermsg = getErrorMsg();
    OutputDebugString(ermsg.c_str());

    std::wostringstream os;
    os << "Error filling buffer with exported certificates from store \n";
    os << "Error code" << GetLastError() << "\n";
    printf("Error exporting certificates: %d\n", GetLastError());
    goto fail;
}

fail:
    if (hCertStore)
        CertCloseStore(hCertStore, 0);


It's something like "create a memory-based store, add a linked reference of the cert(s) you want, export that store, then free it".  It will also require that your private key was imported with the Exportable bit set, or it'll fail from REPORT_NOT_ABLE_TO_EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEY.
